# Regex in R: replace only part of a pattern

Tags: regex, r

```
s <- "YXABCDXABCDYX"
```

I want to use a regular expression to return `ABCDABCD`, i.e. 4 characters on each side of central `"X"` but not including the `"X"`.
Note that `"X"` is always in the center with 6 **letters** on each side.

I can find the central pattern with e.g. `"[A-Z]{4}X[A-Z]{4}"`, but can I somehow let the return be the first and third group in `"([A-Z]{4})(X)([A-Z]{4})"`?

Comment: you almost got it `gsub('.*([A-Z]{4})(X)([A-Z]{4}).*', '\\1\\3', s)`

Comment: Yeah, I was trying something with replacement="\\1" (etc) but I didnt quite understand it. You can put it as answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your regex `"([A-Z]{4})(X)([A-Z]{4})"` won't match your string since you have characters before the first capture group `([A-Z]{4})`, so you can add `.*` to match any character (`.`) 0 or more times (`*`) until your first capture group.

You can reference the groups in `gsub`, for example, using `\\n` where n is the nth capture group

```
s <- "YXABCDXABCDYX"

gsub('.*([A-Z]{4})(X)([A-Z]{4}).*', '\\1\\3', s)
# [1] "ABCDABCD"
```

which is basically matching the entire string and replacing it with whatever was captured in groups 1 and 3 and pasting that together.

Another way would be to use `(?i)` which is case-insensitive matching along with `[a-z]` or `\\w`

```
gsub('(?i).*(\\w{4})(x)(\\w{4}).*', '\\1\\3', s)
# [1] "ABCDABCD"
```

Or `gsub('.*(.{4})X(.{4}).*', '\\1\\2', s)` if you like dots

Comment: Or `gsub('(.{4})X(.{4})|.', '\\1\\2', s)`